# Search on document libraries using query webpart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-query

I have SharePoint 2013 team site with 25 lists and libraries, what I need to do is to create a search webpart just to search four document libraries? is this achievable with search query webpart?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

You could go to search results web part -> edit web part -> change query -> You could go to site settings -> select a query -> result source -> set Documents as result source.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your message, I manage to get to one document library, is there anyway I can add the second one in here?

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you? If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Hi Emily, you answered all my questions I had, my last question is, is there anyway we can filter the results. What happen after adding the WebPart is all the search result from the four document libraries will show up on the page and I was wondering if we can filter the search?

Comment: You could use refiners to your search results page in the SharePoint Server. Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/how-to-add-refiners-to-your-search-results-page

Comment: If the answer helps you, please remember to mark it as answer, it will help other who may have similar issue to find the correct answer quickly.